# ROUNDUP function with condition in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a DAX formula for EXCEL column with the name ED2

FORMULA:

```
=IF ( [ED1] - INT ( [ED1] ) > 0.5, ROUNDUP ( [ED1], 0 ), INT ( [ED1] ) )
```

So if ED1 column has a value greater than 0.5 then it should roundup else rounddown

Example:

> [image]

Comment: So what are you looking for - an SQL function, inline code, ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *Round* function to achieve that.

```
SELECT Round(ED1,0) AS Rounded;
```

Here is a link for round function details: [msdn link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

**Update**:

As mentioned in comment, this is not working in some cases. you can use following code:

```
Select IIF((ED1%1)>0.5,Ceiling(ED1),Floor(ED1)) As Rounded
```

Code for your case:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ED1 DECIMAL(8,2));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
(1),(1.25),(1.5),(1.75),
(2),(2.25),(2.5),(2.75),
(3),(3.25),(3.5),(3.75),
(4);
SELECT ED1,ED2=IIF(ED1%1>0.5,CEILING(ED1),FLOOR(ED1)) FROM @tbl
```

and the output is:

[image: output result]

Comment: That doesn't do what was asked for - Round(3.5, 0) gives 4, the excel function given returns 3

Comment: @DancingFool, yes, thats right, I have updated the answer.

Comment: Im using a case statement
ED2 = CASE 
   WHEN ED1 = 1.0 THEN 1 
   WHEN ED1 = 1.25 THEN 1
   WHEN ED1 = 1.50 THEN 1
   WHEN ED1 = 1.75 THEN 2
   WHEN ED1 = 2.00 THEN 2
   WHEN ED1 = 2.25 THEN 2
   WHEN ED1 = 2.50 THEN 2
   WHEN ED1 = 2.75 THEN 3
   WHEN ED1 = 3.00 THEN 3
   WHEN ED1 = 3.25 THEN 3
   WHEN ED1 = 3.50 THEN 3
   WHEN ED1 = 3.75 THEN 4
   WHEN ED1 = 4.00 THEN 4
   ELSE 0 END
But I want it to be more robust than declaring the values 
Its work fine in Excel but not in SQL
Is there a better way to do this in SQL

Comment: @PowerBI, it is working, I have updated the answer with more explanation.

Comment: Awesome, yes it works
This is what I was looking for
Thanks so much
Also, I tried it for other decimal numbers like 1.65, 2.11 for which the results should be 2 and 2
Thanks again for you help

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @ED float = 3.5;
Select case when @ED - FLOOR(@ED) > 0.5 THEN CEILING(@ED) ELSE FLOOR(@ED) END;
```

Note that this will probably not work as expected for negative numbers